# Shell Script - Add strong quote to each line with delimiter

Tags: linux, shell

Want to add strong quote around each line of devices name.
Ex.
Input:
/dev/sda
/dev/sbd

Output desire: '/dev/sda','/dev/sdb'

Already create a command to merge the lines with comma, but can't add quotes around the output.

```
devices=$(echo `ls -l /dev/*sd* | awk '{ print $9 }' | paste -s -d,-`)
```

Result: `/dev/sda,/dev/sdb`

What command can be used to add strong quote around each line?

Comment: Note that in general, you should never have quotes *in your data*. Correctly done, shell quoting should only be *syntax*, note *data*, and data should never be parsed as syntax unless absolutely essential.

Comment: Also -- which shell, and which version? Bash 5.0 has `${var@Q}` support.

Comment: @scapy : If you **really** want to have the quotes (but why?), you can add them in the awk `print` statement.

Comment: @user1934428: because I have to pass like that to the installation configuration settings, it only accepts the devices around quotes

Comment: If making with this I can add quotes around the output devices, but the comma is ignored not know why: `while IFS= read -r line; do x="'$line'"; echo "$x"; done < <(ls -l /dev/asm/*1 |awk '{print $9}'| paste -s -d"'", -)` The output : '/dev/asm/data01'/dev/asm/redo1'

Answer (score 1):

With bash 5.0, there's a parameter expansion `${var@Q}` which will quote the value that `$var` expands to in such a way as to parse back to its original, literal content. Thus:

```
devices=( /dev/*sd* )           # generate an array with your data, not a string
IFS=,                           # First character of IFS is used for ${array[*]}
printf '%s\n' "${devices[*]@Q}" # Expand each argument quoted, and join with comma from IFS
```

That said, writing code of this form is a "code smell" -- it implies that something is not compliant with best practices. One typically should avoid putting quotes or escaping in data, but instead store that data in a format that doesn't *require* quotes or escaping at all. (For a list of C strings, for example, this typically means a NUL-delimeted list; for a native bash structure, the equivalent is an array).

Comment: Thanks for you reply, but can't do with IFS. I need to format output as as string with strong quote to be used by a installation software. Need to put both devices found around strong quotes, with IFS=, I can only pass a comma between devices (the paste -s -d, - already did that). Can't find a command to do that

Comment: I don't understand what part of the comment above describes a reason you can't use `IFS`. Yes, `IFS` only adds the commas, but a different part of the answer (the `@Q`) adds the quotes. Combine the two, and you've got the commas, *and* you've got the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so after some test I was able to do it, if anyone need I will put here :

`while IFS= read -r line; do x="'$line'"; echo "$x"; done < <(ls -l /dev/nvme*n1 |awk '{print $10}'| paste -s -d, -| sed 's/,/'\',''\''/g')`

The output will be like this:

'/dev/nvme0n1','/dev/nvme1n1','/dev/nvme2n1','/dev/nvme3n1','/dev/nvme4n1'

Comment: Don't use `ls` in scripts; it's a tool meant for interactive, human use only. See [ParsingLs](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: `var_list=$(printf "'%s'," /dev/nvme*n1); var_list=${var_list%,}` would be a less buggy way to get an equivalent value assigned to the `var_list` variable, and far faster to run. ("Less buggy" meaning it'll do fewer unexpected things when the set of devices matching your glob include filenames with spaces or other patterns you don't expect).